Error Module not found despite of Installation of the python package from github
I am installing a package which is available in github examplepackage
$pip3 install examplepackage  
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting examplepackage
  Using cached ExamplePackage-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: examplepackage
Successfully installed examplepackage-0.1.3

$pip3 list | grep -i example  
ExamplePackage                0.1.3

I am trying to run below code:
from ExamplePackage.example_module import example_function

example_function()

and expecting below to be printed from example_function() from example_module:
Hello World! I bet you didn't expect that.
But i am getting below error:
$python3 test.py              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saurav/face_detection/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ExamplePackage.example_module import example_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ExamplePackage.example_module'

Please Help.

In Python, case does matter.   from examplepackage.example_module...

This is quite interesting. I installed the package using pip install examplepackage which worked. However, the import statements provided in the package repo didn't work.
So I decided to inspect the package and discovered that the actual package installed is ExamplePackage not examplepackage. Furthermore, there was nothing like example_module and example_function() meaning the following code provided on their GitHub would throw an error:
import examplepackage
examplepackage.example_module.example_function()

Looking at the contents of ExamplePackage (i.e. the actual package installed), we have SubPackage1 and SubPackage2. SubPackage1 contains a module1.py file from which we can import a function fun1. SubPackage2 contains a folder named GrandPackage and a module2.py having a function fun2.
There's no existence of examplepackage, example_module or example_function() in this package. What you can do is:
from ExamplePackage.SubPackage1.module1 import fun1

If you're using Python3, this will throw a SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)? So let's look at the contents of module1:
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: mymodule1.py

def fun1():
    print "Module1"

You can see the print statement in fun1 is without parenthesis (probably written in an archaic version of python). To fix this, add parenthesis to your print statement as suggested in the error message print("Module1"). Run the correct import statement again and phew, it now works. Repeat this for any other function you wish to import as they are not written in Python3.

The github repo has nothing to do with the pypi package, there is a reason the github does not mention installation via pip
